# Can "polar numbers" be added in a sensible way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{P}$ denote the set of all "polar numbers," by which I just mean pairs of real numbers $(r,\theta).$ Note in particular that $r$ is allowed to be negative. Then we can structure $\mathbb{P}$ via the following definitions.

1. $(r,\theta)(r',\theta') = (rr',\theta+\theta')$
2. $-(r,\theta) = (-r,\theta)$
3. $\overline{(r,\theta)} = (r,-\theta)$
4. $(r,\theta)^{-1} = (r^{-1},-\theta)$ whenever $r \neq 0$.
5. $0_\mathbb{P} = (0,0), \quad 1_\mathbb{P} = (1,0)$

**Question.** Is there a way to structure $\mathbb{P}$ with a notion of addition, such that firstly, it satisfies a good chunk of the field axioms (we need to take a quotient before it has any chance of being a genuine field), and secondly, the unique function $f : \mathbb{P} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(r,\theta) = r \exp(i\theta)$ becomes a homomorphism? By which I mean, in particular, that $f((r,\theta)+(r',\theta'))$ should equal $f(r,\theta)+f(r',\theta').$

Comment: Your $\mathbb{P}$ as presently defined can't serve as the multiplicative structure for a field, because it's not the case that $0_{\mathbb{P}}p = 0_{\mathbb{P}}$ for all $p\in\mathbb{P}$; you need to craft an equivalence class to handle $0$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, you're right of course. I might edit later to fix this issue, but its kind of tangential to the *actual* question I'm intereted in, which is: can we add these things in a sensible way?

Comment: It's a solid question (+1) - but I'm not sure that the issue _is_ tangential; the many-to-one nature of the exponential map (and contrariwise, choosing the branch cut for the logarithm) is at the root of the challenge.  You mention negative $r$ in your question, but I strongly suspect the real issue isn't the domain of $r$, it's the domain of $\theta$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, that's an interesting point of view. What else would the domain of $\theta$ be? We don't want it to be $[0,2\pi)$, or else we'll just get the complex numbers, or something similar. I was wanting $\mathbb{P}$ to be "a version of the complex numbers where the number of times you've moved around the origin actually matters."